# Response to "How you doing?"?

Tags: colloquial-language, responses

What is a natural response to "Good to see you. How you doing?"?

Will a natural response include "doing" as in "I'm doing okay" or will "I'm okay" be more natural?

Comment: It's all a matter of opinion. My opinion is if you're confident enough to ignore "standard" grammar and dispense with the verb in *How **are** you doing?* then you should be confident enough to just follow your instincts for the reply. If you hadn't even *noticed* the "syntactically invalid" omission of verbs in ***both*** sentences "Good to see you. How you doing?", you should probably spend more time on that.

Answer (score 2):

Both those are good responses.  There is no fixed response.  You might say

- I'm fine.
- I'm doing okay
- I'm okay
- Really good!

Or you can just respond with a greeting:

- Good to see you too.

It's common to also return the question, so putting it all together a longer response could be:

> Hey there. Good to see you too!  I'm alright, thanks.  How about you?

It is even possible to be negative:

> Hi. Actually, I'm not feeling great right now...

Comment: do both of "I am doing well/good" sound correct to you?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko They are both used by native speakers, at least in the US. I imagine "I am doing good." should raise some eyebrows in Britain. "I'm good." is also quite common in the U.S., probably not in the UK. I think that might be the reason James didn't include it in his answer, as he is a British speaker. I remember years ago at a dinner party at Cambridge, a professor, advanced in years, said to us: "You Americans always find funny ways to use words. You say, 'I'm good.' It sounds funny to me." He meant to tell us the correct expression was, "I'm well." or "I'm fine."

Comment: Perhaps it is obvious.  But it doesn't really matter what you say.  Some thing that is completely "wrong" like "I is very very good", if spoken confidently and with a smile is a great way to respond!  That's much better than robotically saying `I am very well` robotically and with no warmth.  It is much much better than saying nothing.  Remember this is a conversation, not a grammar test!

Comment: @JamesK but `I am doing good` should be `I am doing well` no? native speakers don't find it weired?